# video not embedding in background - Next js and tailwind css

Tags: typescript, next.js, video, tailwind-css

here is the code for app/page.tsx

```js
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <main className='min-h-screen'>
        <video
          muted
          loop
          autoPlay
          className="fixed -top-2 left-0 min-w-full min-h-full -z-50 object-cover"
        >
          <source src= '@/assets/video/videoBg.mp4'type="video/mp4" />
          <source src='@/assets/video/videoBg.mp4' type="video/ogg" />
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>

        <div className=" bg-black opacity-80 w-full min-h-[140vh] absolute top-0 left-0 -z-40"></div>
        <div className=" w-full py-10 px-0 flex flex-col justify-end">
          <div className="w-[90%] m-auto flex flex-col items-center gap-10">
            <h1 className="font-medium text-center sm:text-start text-2xl md:text-3xl lg:text-4xl xl:text-5xl leading-loose text-white">
            Empower Your Wellness  Journey with Health Optima
            </h1>
            <h3 className="text-white text-3xl font-light">Your Ultimate Health and Wellness Companion</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  )
}
```

unable to render the video in the structure

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDXZg.png)

there might be problem with tailwind css

[browser preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7XHM.png)

Answer (score 0):

put your videos inside `public` directory.

`public/videos/videoBg.mp4`
then use it as
`/videos/videoBg.mp4`